# MySQL select on PHP can't get it to work

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am having a problem retrieveing information from a MySQL Data Base. Could you help me out? This is the code I wrote:

```
<?php 
                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notas LIMIT 1 ORDER BY id DESC");
                        while($nt = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="nuevos_1">
                        <div class="over_descripcion">
                            <div class="over_title">
                                <h3><a href="/nota/<?php echo $nt[fecha]."/".$nt[titulolower] ?>"><?php echo $nt[titulo] ?></a></h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="over_autor">
                                <span><b>Por: </b><a href="/autor/<?php print $nt[autor]; ?>"><?php print ucwords(str_replace("-", " ", $nt[autor])); ?></a> <?php echo $nt[fecha] ?></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="over_texto">
                                <span><b><?php echo strtoupper(str_replace("-", " ", $nt[categoria])) ?></b> <a href="/nota/<?php echo $nt[fecha]."/".$nt[titulolower] ?>"><?php echo substr(strip_tags($nt[texto]), 0, 240)."..." ?></a></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="over_ver_mas">
                                <input type="button" value="Leer más" onclick="location.href='/nota/<?php echo $nt[fecha]."/".$nt[titulolower] ?>'" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="/nota/<?php echo $nt[fecha]."/".$nt[titulolower] ?>">
                          <img src="http://<?php echo $nt[imagen] ?>" border="0" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php }; ?>
```

Nothing inside the SELECT notas database is showing. It is simply gone...

Thanks!

Comment: you need to open a connection first. mysql_connect(...); do u have this?

Comment: In the future, temporarily do `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notas LIMIT 1 ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());` to see what the error emssage is. That will help you fix it. Then remove the `or die`... portion because it can reveal sensitive information. Another thing you can do is install [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) and run your query in there. That will also show you the error.

Comment: I would like to point out that you are accessing the $nt[] array in an unsupported (deprecated) manner.  Instead of using $nt[index] , you should be using $nt['index'] .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your query to

```
SELECT * FROM notas ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 5):

Limit 1 has to go after the ORDER BY

Comment: I do the same thing all the time. I told my wife to remind me that I am an idiot when I can't figure out code. It helps to jog my memory about what I am being an idiot about, and I fix it faster. She still won't call me an idiot though, she's too nice.

Answer (score 0):

what does the error message say

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notas LIMIT 1 ORDER BY id DESC");
if (mysql_error()) {
  die(mysql_error()); 
}
```

Comment: a simpler way to write the same thing all in one line is $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table") or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 0):

The other answers above have it correct - you've got a syntax error in your query. If you'd done the basic step of having:

```
$result = mysql_query(..) or die(mysql_error());
```

you'd have seen the error message. Never EVER assume that a query succeeds. Always check for error conditions.

As well, you've got a minor syntax bug in your output:

```
... <a href="/nota/<?php echo $nt[fecha]."/".$nt[titulolower] ?>"> ...
                                ^^^^^
```

Your array keys are not quoted, which means they're interpreted as `define()`'d constants. PHP is polite and will treat those constants as strings if there actually is not constant with that name, but it will issue a warning for every occurence. It should be:

```
<?php echo $nt['fecha'] ... ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't too well about PHP, but your select statement limits to just one result. You might want to change this line:

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notas LIMIT 1 ORDER BY id DESC");
```

You will not get more than one result as it is.